# Integration of undefined function MAT Question

Tags: integration

[image: Question]

I have started this question by defining $ f(x) $ as two functions over two domains. $$ f(x) = x + 1 ,  -1 \leq x \leq 0 $$ $$ f(x) = -x+1, 0 \leq x \leq 1 $$

I then find $f(x^2-1)$ which is $$f(x^2-1) = (x^2-1)+1=x^2 $$ $$f(x^2-1) = -(x^2-1)+1=-x^2+2$$

Now, I am unsure which function we use to solve $$\int_{-1}^1 f(x^2-1) \ dx $$

I am not the best at mathematics, so would appreciate a simple but informative explanation!

Thanks

Comment: You just split the integral $\int_{-1}^1=\int_{-1}^0+\int_0^1$ and use your definition for each part

Comment: you started well, now break the integral into two integrals according to two intervals that you obtained

Answer (score 1):

For $-1 \le x \le 1$, we have  $0 \le x^2 \le 1 $ and hence $-1 \le x^2 -1 \le 0$.

Hence for $-1 \le x \le 1,$ $f(x^2-1)= x^2$.

$$\int_{-1}^1 x^2 \, dx = 2\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx= \frac23$$

Comment: Sorry, I might be a bit slow today, how did you come to the conclusion that it would be the $f(x)=x^2 $ we would be integrating as opposed to the $f(x) = -x^2+2$ function?

Comment: The input of $f$, which is $x^2-1$ takes value from$-1$ to $0$, hence we follow the first rule.